# getting error in color authentication password

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, colors, password-protection

I am trying to create color password but i am getting this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

my code is this and please help me ....
thnxx in advance :)

```
protected void Button_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username ='" + TextBoxUserName.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    conn.Close();
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string checkPasswordQuery = "select Password from UserData where Username ='" + TextBoxUserName.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
        string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ","");

        if (password == TextBoxPassword.Text)
        {

            Response.Write("Password is correct");


            string checkcolorQuery = "select Color1,Color2,Color3,Color4 from Username='" + TextBoxUserName.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand colorCom = new SqlCommand(checkcolorQuery, conn);

            string color = colorCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); // **getting error here**
            if (color == TextBoxColor1.Text && color == TextBoxColor2.Text && color == TextBoxColor3.Text && color == TextBoxColor4.Text) 

            {
              //  Session["New"] = TextBoxUserName.Text;
                Response.Write("Color Priority is correct");
                Response.Redirect("User.aspx");
            }

            else
            {
                Response.Write("Color Priority is  not correct");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Password is  not correct");
        }


    }
  else
    {
        Response.Write("Username is not correct");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: On which line exactly? What is the type of `Username` column and  `TextBoxUserName.Text`? Use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation. And don't store your password as a plain text.

Comment: getting error here... string color = colorCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

Comment: You should always try your sql statements in your database management studio first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is currently

`select Color1,Color2,Color3,Color4 from Username='foo'`

Surely you need it to be something like

`select Color1,Color2,Color3,Color4 from tablename where Username='foo'`

You should also change the way you are executing your SQL.
Use something like this to execute your SQL.

```
    public static void ExecuteSQL(string sqlCommand, Dictionary<string,object> parameters )
    {
        using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            dbConn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, dbConn))
            {
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                    {
                        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                    }
                }
                dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            dbConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

So in your code you'd just have

```
 string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username =@username";
 var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 parameters.Add("@username", TextBoxUserName.Text);
 ExecuteSQL(checkuser, parameters);
```

Comment: You should also mention about using _parameterized queries_ and [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`. +1 for the fastest gun in the west.

Comment: right bro it work but now i have another problem... i am giving correct color priorty but it is showing that password is correct and color priorty is incorrect :( could you please look my code againfor this ...

Answer (score 2):

### Problem #1

```
string checkcolorQuery = "select Color1,Color2,Color3,Color4 from Username='" + TextBoxUserName.Text + "'";
```

This is the line that is causing the error you're getting. "from Username='whatever'" is not valid SQL, presumably (based on other queries in your code) you meant "from UserData where Username='whatever'".

### Problem #2

While we're on the subject, though, this is a textbook example of an SQL injection vulnerability, and that should really be addressed too. Consider what would happen if somebody typed the following into your TextBoxUserName textbox:

';drop table UserData;--

**Important:** don't actually try this, *think* about it instead.

### Problem #3

```
colorCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

ExecuteScalar() is only for use when you're expecting a single value. It works fine in your first query, because all that's being returned is a single value (the contents of one row's password field). In this second query, though, you're returning *four* values - only from a single row, true, but you're selecting four fields (Color1 through Color4).

What you should do here is use ExecuteReader() instead, which will return a data reader which you can use to extract those four values and then proceed to compare them the user's input.

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
string checkcolorQuery = "select Color1,Color2,Color3,Color4 from Username='" + TextBoxUserName.Text + "'";
```

is the problem.  `Username` is a column, not a table.  It should be

```
string checkcolorQuery = "select Color1,Color2,Color3,Color4 from UserData where Username='" + TextBoxUserName.Text + "'";
```

Comment: right bro it work but now i have another problem... i am giving correct color priorty but it is showing that password is correct and color priorty is incorrect :( could you please look my code again for this

Comment: You are calling `ExecuteScalar()` when you are `SELECT`ing four columns.  Thus you are only getting the first color back, and you are comparing that color to all four text boxes.  You should use `ExecuteReader()` and get the four columns into four separate string variables.

Comment: i use ExecuteReader() but si am in same problem .

Comment: Done :)  i replace my code with this " string color = colorCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ","");"

Comment: you have also correct answer but i am sorry bro i can select only one correct answer between two user ... #theedom has just anw before you